# Put two column side by side

Tags: html, css

I want put this two value together (Side by side), as following image, but i not know how is it? see in demo my try, (i want without change css and class name and just with cjange html and use style in element done it)

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/33NBg/1/

**IMAGE:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8FIn.gif

Comment: Your HTML structure is wrong, because you have to separate rows. You want both _list_units_ to be in one `<div class="rediuses column">`. -- FYI: You have i.e. double IDs `residence_name`. IDs should be unique! -- If you want to keep both columns you will have to change more CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `float: left;` in your css in your `.column` class.

Answer (score 1):

Your html structure in not correct. It is having two different rows instead of two div's in a single row.

Here is code :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.neginph.com/style.css"/>

<fieldset>
    <div class="find_input">
        <div class="rediuses column" id="residence_name" style="float: none; -webkit-column-count: 0; -webkit-column-rule-width: 0px; -webkit-column-rule-style: initial; -webkit-column-rule-color: initial; display: block; height:40px; width:500px;">
            <div class="list_units" style="background-color: #E2EBF1; width:200px;">
                <div class="auto_box" style="float:left; width:90px; margin-right:10px;">
                    <b class="search_hotel" style="background-color: #ffffff;"><span><b>12121112</b></span></b>
                </div>
                <div class="auto_box">
                   <b class="search_hotel" style="background-color: #ffffff; width:90px;"><span><b>12121112</b></span></b>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```